Can't connect to Identity views
I recently created a Windows Server 2022 Standard with SQL Server 2019, posted my .NET Core 6 app and everything seemed to go alright... until I logged on and tried to open a Identity page.
Server logs keeps telling me my SQL Connection its wrong, but I'm connected via SQL Server Management Studio correctly and login, which depends on this works to, it just breaks when loading a page that requieres using my dbcontext.
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SNI_PN11, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover, SqlAuthenticationMethod authType)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
         at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReader(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.InitializeReader(Enumerator enumerator)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.<>c.<MoveNext>b__19_0(DbContext _, Enumerator enumerator)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
         at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetSingle[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Boolean& found)
         at lambda_method307(Closure , QueryContext )
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
         at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
         at CALJO.Controllers.HomeController._LoadUserInfo(UserManager`1 um, ClaimsPrincipal us) in C:\Users\Luis\source\repos\CALJO\Controllers\HomeController.cs:line 759
         at AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Areas_Identity_Pages_Account_Manage_PersonalData.ExecuteAsync() in C:\Users\Luis\source\repos\CALJO\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\Manage\PersonalData.cshtml:line 0
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageCoreAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderPageAsync(IRazorPage page, ViewContext context, Boolean invokeViewStarts)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorView.RenderAsync(ViewContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewExecutor.ExecuteAsync(ViewContext viewContext, String contentType, Nullable`1 statusCode)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|30_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)



My NuGET Packages:

My appsettings (censored by obvious reasons):
{
    "ConnectionStrings": {
        "DefaultConnection": "Server=SRVJJOO\\MULHACEN2;Database=CALJO;User Id=XXXX;Password=XXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
        "ApplicationDbContextConnection": "Server=SRVJJOO\\MULHACEN2;Database=CALJO;User Id=XXXXX;Password=XXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
    },
        "Logging": {
            "LogLevel": {
                "Default": "Information",
                "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "SmtpSettings": {
            "Server": "smtp.gmail.com",
            "Port": 587,
            "SenderName": "XXXXXXX",
            "SenderEmail": "XXXXXXXXX",
            "Username": "XXXXXXX",
            "Password": "XXXXXXX"
        },

        "AllowedHosts": "*"
    }

My program.cs file:
using CALJO.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CALJO.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using CALJO.Services;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Configuration;
using CALJO.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Configura la protección de datos
builder.Services.AddDataProtection()
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "keys")))
    .SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(30));

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options =>
{
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
    // Configura opciones de autenticación adicionales aquí si es necesario
})
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
    options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied";
});

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CALJOContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services.AddScoped<HomeController>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDatosService, DatosService>();

// Configure SmtpSettings
builder.Services.Configure<SmtpSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("SmtpSettings"));

// Register the email sender service
builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, SmtpEmailSender>();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        Path.Combine(app.Environment.ContentRootPath, "UserImages")),
    RequestPath = "/UserImages"
});

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US"); // Establece la cultura en inglés (Estados Unidos)
cultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."; // Establece el separador decimal en punto

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();


Steps followed:

Opened 1433 port just for entries on my firewall
Allowed remote connections to my DB
Allowed TCP / IP connections
Specified port on connectionString
Triplechecked my connectionString
Changed my user and password on connection string
Stablished IPAII TCP port to 1433

My error log shows like if my controller was beeing called on the PC I developed the app instead of in which server is executing. Of course this works perfectly fine on local.
I looked for similar issues on stackoverflow but nothing seemed to work, even stablishing the LoadUserProfile in my IIS didn't make a change.

I'm guessing you installed SQL Server Express - which defaults to only having Shared Memory enabled, with TCP/IP disabled, so Server=SRVJJOO\MULHACEN2 won't work - you'll need Server=(local)\MULHACEN2 - or enable TCP/IP - and faff around with self-signed certs.

@Dai I supposedly already activated de TCP/IP, but tryed the (local) configuration and had same output (no luck)

Windows has a telnet client (you may need to install it via Control Panel). Use that to try to connect on port 1433.

@Dai From Server PC the telnet gives a TCP Test Success, from other pc in the same Network, it fails

You didn't say you were trying to connect from another machine. Let's ignore that for now. Is MSSQL and IIS+ASP.NET all running locally within the same Windows machine? If they're both running locally then why do you need external connections and firewall rules, etc?

After you changed configurations in SQL Server Configuration Manager and Windows Firewall... did you remember to restart both the SQL Server instance as well as the SQL Browser service?

@Dai because this is Production server, not localhost development

@AlwaysLearning Yes sir, i always do that

@LuisBauer You didn't include that important detail in your question post...

My bad thought deploying the app was clear enough, please if any doubt rises let me know and i will add the necessary information. Sorry for any missunderstanding.

"Error Locating Server/Instance Specified" likely means that it can't resolve the Server-Name RVJJOO to a machine network address. What kind of network is this? You can only use the short-name (like RVJJOO or RVJJOO\INSTANCENAME) in a small LAN where single-label machine-names are registered in AD DNS (for example) - if it's anything else you'll need to use the full DNS name - or its IP address.

Thanks for you reply @Dai and sorry in advance for my lack of experience in the matter, as referenced before, its my 1st time deploying an app.
Server PC its on my LAN but its properly opened to be accesible to anyone in the internet, i can access it from any device inside or outside my LAN, this issue only appears when accessing private Identity pages that requiere LINQ to fetch data.
SQL Server instance is in the same PC as my Web App is deployed, thats why i thought using just the SQL Server instance, SRVJJOO\MULHACEN2 was enough,
Given this context, should i make any change?

Again, thanks you for your time and patience, i really appreciate it, and sorry if anything i'm trying to explain its out of scope, i'm trying my sincere best :)

"SQL Server instance is in the same PC as my Web App is deployed" - what do you mean by this?

@Dai Took an old PC, Installed Windows Server 2022 in it, opened the relevant ports, installed SQL Server Express Edition and SQL Server Management, Imported my DB Structure, added my APP to the inetpub > wwwroot directory by publishing my net core application with Visual Studio 2022, adjusted my appsettings.
App its live on the internet and can be accesible from any device, but Databased views cannot be shown.
What i mean is, i literally have my DB and SQL Server in the same PC where my web app is hosted, i'm not using any online hosting. Did i do something wrong? sry again.

@LuisBauer This is not something we can really help you with on StackOverflow. You need to speak to your hosting provider.

I am my hosting provider...
